# How do I get the DISTRIB_CODENAME?

Tags: bash, lsb

Which is the shortest way to get the variable `$DISTRIB_CODENAME` from `/etc/lsb-release`?

I want to make this somewhat shorter:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \
  "deb http://some-repo/ubuntu $(grep CODENAME lsb-release |sed s/^.*=//g) main"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can source that file in `bash` (or any Bourne-like shell) to set them as shell variables:

```
source /etc/lsb-release
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://some-repo/ubuntu $DISTRIB_CODENAME main"
```

Answer (score 7):

The command `lsb-release` has an option to display `codename` according to the distribution release:

```
apt-get install lsb-release
lsb_release -c -s
```

So you can try to rewrite it like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://some-repo/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main"
```

For details, check `man lsb_release`.